# What does "сошелся" (or "сошёлся"?) mean?

Tags: глаголы

I'm reading Tolstoy's Исповедь, and in the second chapter it says:

> Двадцати шести лет я приехал после войны в Петербург и *сошелся* с
>   писателями.

Did he live together with other writers? What is the infinitive form of that word?

Comment: he made some friends among writers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, he didn't live with other writers. This is a pretty old-style text. In this context `сошелся` means just `met` (`встретился` / `познакомился` / `подружился`).
The infinive form of `сошелся` is `сойтись`.

Answer (score 7):

to meet - *встретить, познакомиться, сойтись*

In this context, *сошелся* means that he met writers and started having some kind of relationships, communicating and meeting up with them, you can even say that he started becoming a friend to them and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say `got together` is appropriate. Or `connected with` perhaps.